# Jack server not working on Raspbian

Tags: python, audio, alsa

I wrote a little python app (using [PyDub](http://pydub.com)), that plays sound files.
Everytime I run it, I get the these errors:

```
ALSA lib pulse.c:243(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

jack_client_new: deprecated
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Jack server is not running or cannot be started.
jack_client_new: deprecated
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Jack server is not running or cannot be started.
jack_client_new: depricated
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Jack server is not running or cannot be started.
jack_client_new: depricated
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Jack server is not running or cannot be started.
```

I can hear some sound, but it's only crackling, which is not very similar to the original sound I can hear when I play it my laptop.

I've searched in the web for hours, but everything I try causes new errors or doesn't change anything.
If I start the Jack server by running `jack_control start` or  `qjackctl`, the PyDub import runs endless. (It seems as if connecting to the jack server never ended) 
I heard about solutions using PulseAudio, but i want to use the Jack server directly, because it's latency offset seems to be much shorter than PulseAudio's.
I followed [this](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Jack_%28plugin%29) introductions to redirect every program to the Jack server.

I'm using Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 1, with Python 2.7.

Sorry if my english is bad, it's not my first language.
Thanks for any advice.